# Why does SE about page say "programming community"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, tour

[StackExchange about](https://stackexchange.com/about) page says:

> The world’s largest **programming
> community** is growing

I want to know why it says "programming community" since SE is actually group of 150+ communities in which considerable are unrelated to programming?

Also it is not supposed to talk about Stack Overflow as it has it's own [about](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) page plus it is confirmed from SE logo.

Comment: Historically, SE *is* an expansion of SO. A growth of it, if you will. And since SO is still the largest site by far, it's not completely inappropriate to explain the network as "SO and friends".